# How can I use the command '_' ("nth word") using VI mode in BASH?

Tags: bash, vi, readline, shortcut

[This cheat sheet for VI keyboard shortcuts for Bash](http://www.catonmat.net/download/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet.txt) mentions a `_` shortcut:

```
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
| _            | Inserts the n-th word of the previous command in the       |
|              | current line.                                              |
'--------------+------------------------------------------------------------'
```

but I don't really understand how to use it. Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the next:

```
$ set -o vi
$ echo 1 2 3 4 5   #command
1 2 3 4 5
<ESC>3_
2               #third word of previous command
```

Answer (score 3):

In vi-command mode, you type a number then the key.  For example if you run the command

```
$ ls -l /long/file/name.txt
```

then as your next command you can type

```
$ less <ESC>3_
```

(meaning the Escape key, 3 and _)  it will insert the 3rd argument from the previous command, giving you

```
$ less /long/file/name.txt
```